# Removing elements from [[Int]] list if the numbers appeared before in the same list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I have something like this:

```
[[1,3,2],[5,6],[3,8],[10,11],[13,6]]
```

And I want to filter out the third and last list, so that it becomes:

```
[[1,3,2],[5,6],[10,11]]
```

The logic is to remove the lists if any of the numbers "appeared before" (in the case of `[3,8]`, the number `3` appears in the first list).

I can only think of non-FP methods to do this. My goal is to learn Haskell in a "good way". How can this be done?

Comment: Consider passing a set of already-seen numbers between invocations of the function that scans your list of lists. (Remember how a partial result is passed around during invocation of `fold`).

Comment: I have no mood to make a proper answer of this (and it's not really efficient), but a possible solution is `nubBy (\l m -> not . null $ intersect l m)`.

Comment: Say you have a list `[[1,3,2],[5,6],[3,8],[10,11],[8],[13,6]]`, should `[8]` be part of the output too? You did not "emit" `[3,8]`, but still have observed it so to speak.

Comment: While the desired semantics of this function are somewhat ambiguous, this should be a good starting point: `($[]) . fst . foldl (\(r,seen) l -> (if any (\`elem\` seen) l then r else r . (l:) , l++seen)) (id,[])`

Comment: @CommuSoft the entire `[3,8]` item should go away. I'm trying to do something like @9000 suggested, building a new `[Int]` list of "previously seen numbers" and passing it around, still unsuccessful..

Comment: @leftaroundabout wow that totally seems to work. I have no idea how/why though. Care to put it in an answer and explain it a bit? What does `nubBy` do?

Comment: @cambraca: [read the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nubBy). When you don't know where the documentation is, [ask Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=nubBy). When you don't even know the name of a function you need, [ask Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Eq+a+%3D%3E+[a]+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[a]).

Comment: @leftaroundabout that's useful, I wasn't aware of all of those resources. Thanks!

Comment: @cambraca CommuSoft's question was not about the `[3,8]` item -- which we all agree should not be emitted -- but about the `[8]` item that appears later in their sample input list. A shorter example is: what should the behavior on `[[0], [0,1], [1]]` be, `[[0]]` or `[[0], [1]]`?

Comment: @DanielWagner @CommuSoft sorry, I missed that! That's a good question. The `[8]` item should be kept, since `8` is not in the previous lists.

Answer (score 5):

What about this: you use an accumulator like a [Data.HashSet](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashmap-1.3.0.1/docs/Data-HashSet.html) and then use some kind of filter approach like:

```
import Data.HashSet
import Data.Hashable

somefilter :: (Hashable a, Ord a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
somefilter = sf empty

sf :: (Hashable a, Ord a) => Set a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
sf hs (x:xs) | any (flip member hs) x = tl
             | otherwise = x : tl
             where tl = sf (foldr insert hs x) xs
sf _ [] = []
```

Then the demo:

```
*Main> somefilter [[1,3,2],[5,6],[3,8],[10,11],[13,6]]
[[1,3,2],[5,6],[10,11]]
```

You can of course use another datastructure (list, treeset, whatever) to store the values you've encountered thus far. A `HashSet` is simply a reasonable choice because of the low lookup and insertion time complexity.

**Edit**

Evidently time complexity is not easy to measure for lazy programming. If you intend to generate the entire list, the time complexities can be derived from the [documentation of `Data.IntMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.2.1/docs/Data-IntMap.html#t:IntMap).

Given that the total number of elements is *N* (not to be confused with the number of *lists*), and we consider the number of bits of the `Int` *W* fixed (32 or 64), both `insert` and `lookup` are done in constant time. This means that the total time complexity is *O(N)*.

For the `nubBy` solution, although the time complexity for [`intersect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intersect) this probably runs in *O(m n)* with *m* the number of items in one list, and *n* the number of elements in another list. This is done for each list against all previous. So in case there are *O(k)* lists, the time complexity is *O(k<sup>2</sup> a<sup>2</sup>)* with *a* the average number of items in a list. Since *a k=N*, the time complexity is thus approximately *O(N<sup>2</sup>)*.

**Edit 2**

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138605/removing-elements-from-int-list-if-the-numbers-appeared-before-in-the-same-l/34138902?noredirect=1#comment56042273_34138605), you can rewrite the function in order to meet the new specifications:

```
import Data.HashSet
import Data.Hashable

somefilter2 :: (Hashable a, Ord a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
somefilter2 = sf2 empty

sf2 :: (Hashable a, Ord a) => Set a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
sf2 hs (x:xs) | any (flip member hs) x = sf2 hs xs
              | otherwise = x : sf2 (foldr insert hs x) xs
sf2 _ [] = []
```

With the difference between `somefilter` and `somefilter2`:

```
*Main> somefilter [[1,3,2],[5,6],[3,8],[10,11],[8],[13,6]]
[[1,3,2],[5,6],[10,11]]
*Main> somefilter2 [[1,3,2],[5,6],[3,8],[10,11],[8],[13,6]]
[[1,3,2],[5,6],[10,11],[8]]
```

there is only a difference in the recursive part of `sf`: now you only add elements to the `Set` in case you "*emit*" an element.

Comment: Any idea how this compares to @leftroundabout's solution in terms of performance? (`nubBy (\l m -> not . null $ intersect l m)`)

Comment: @cambraca: the `intersect` and `numBy` are not fully specified, but based on what I've seen before, I expect quadratic time complexity whereas using a `HashSet` results in linear time complexity (see edit).

Comment: @CommuSoft The standard library includes `Data.List`, which contains both `intersect` and `nubBy`.

Comment: @CommuSoft sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm getting an error on `... => Set a ...`: "Not in scope: type constructor or class 'Set'". Do I need to import something else? Also, I was using Data.List, which apparently has a lot of similar functions to Data.HashSet. Why is this? What's the difference between `filter` or `union` between the two? I assume I can't use them interchangeably.

Comment: @DanielWagner: yes I know. I mean the documentation seems to lack the time complexity.

Comment: @cambraca: did you install the `hashmap` package? There is another package (`unordered-containers`) that uses the same module name...

Comment: @CommuSoft Ah, sorry for the noise, then.